¿ Cómo puedo redireccionar mi link en el html, de modo que me abra en otra ventana cuando se ejecute?
<a herf "https://youtu.be/T4DlpNQAb8c?feature=shared>
Para conocer más sobre ella observa unos de sus videos aquí</a>

Al ejecutar me abre recarga en misma pestaña

Revisa el parámetro target en tu enlace, es el que indica en que destino abrir el contenido. El posible valor que te puede interesar es "blank"

Para ser exactos es "_blank". Más info

Sería de tal modo esto:
<a href="https://youtu.be/T4DlpNQAb8c?feature=shared" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"></a>

Lo que cumple con lo que quieres es el atributo "target" con el valor "_blank", lo demás se recomienda usar para que el sitio destino no capture información de más.
